# Is it possible to stage multiple sets of changes separately in git?

Tags: git

This is a question (request for advise) about a frequenly used git work flow that I've developed over years of using git.

If I have made lots of changes to a project (multiple changes in multiple files), I often iterate through all the hunks (with git gui) and decide which I want to stage together and then commit the several hunks together with one commit and a descriptive comment.  Then I continue through all the remaining hunks again grouping hunks together into a common commit.

But a problem that often occurs, is on the 3rd or 4th iteration, I discover a hunk which should have been in one of the previous commits.  In this case I temporarily commit the staged changes to something called TMP, commit the hunk in question "amend ", then continue staging the remaining hunks, and comment with message "amend TMP".   After I'm finished committing all the changes, I go back and rebase -i and reorder and squash the "amend..." commits together appropriately.

QUESTION: Is there a better way?

I've wanted to be able to go through the hunks and stage them one by one into separate sets.  And when everything is staged, loop through the staging sets, and commit them one by one with an appropriate comment.   I would also like to accumulate/edit the comment as I build the stage sets.

Does such a feature exist?     What is it called?

One possibility might be to allow a single hunk to be appended to an existing commit, then rebase the later commits, but somehow otherwise leave the work area and staging area effectively unchanged.

This question is similar to [How to create multiple stages in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488910/how-to-create-multiple-stages-in-git) and [Break up multiple changes into separate commits with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948494/break-up-multiple-changes-into-separate-commits-with-git) but those discussions don't really answer my question sufficiently.   Yes, it's possible, but it seems like there must/should be a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I easily fixup a past commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103589/how-can-i-easily-fixup-a-past-commit)

Comment: I acknowledge that you're not exactly asking the same thing, however afaik the answer to the question I've linked is the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Forgive me for saying, but this sounds like an awfully complex workflow.  Do you really need this level of granularity?

Comment: HI Tim, the reason I ask the question is indeed because I'd like to simplify the workflow.  Actually the situation arises frequently.   Say I'm editing code, edit several functions in order to fix a bug.  While doing my edits I notice unrelated comments with errors, so I fix them.   Editing a function means editing defs, call-sites, tests, docs etc.   Now, I'd like to commit each function separately; such a commit includes the def, call-sites, docs, and tests for that function but none other.  1st find foo1 changes, and commit them, then foo2, then foo3 (oops I forgot something for foo1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two git repositories in one directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436125/two-git-repositories-in-one-directory)

Comment: [Multiple staging areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947201/multiple-staging-areas) looks quite related to this workflow and the issue for [Supporting multiple indexes](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2760) for Magit has interesting discussion around this.  (Ah Torek's answer below is quite enlightening as well!)

Comment: Multiple stages would be so useful and greatly increase the quality and logical coherence of commits. Real-world coding often does not fit into the one-logical-task-at-a-time ideal. You're stuck having to do multiple passes over your working tree or doing an interactive rebase. Both of which are too time consuming.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is "no, there's no better way"—but you can experiment with `git worktree add`, perhaps.  (This will run you smack into a different problem, but it may not be a problem after all.)

The problem is that there is only one *index*,<sup>1</sup> which Git calls *the* index, or sometimes the *staging area* or the *cache*.  Meanwhile, no commit, once made, can ever be changed at all.  Not even `git commit --amend` *changes* a commit (we'll get to this later).

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't quite true.  In particular, if you use `git worktree add`, you get one index *per work-tree*.  Git also allows various commands to use a temporary index file; things like `git stash`, and even extra-complicated varieties of `git commit`, use this because `git write-tree` always use the index as their input, but can be pointed to a temporary index.  Actually using a temporary index is going to be far too tricky, though.

---

When you use `git add -p` or some fancier GUI to interactively select particular changes (diff hunks or individual lines or whatever) to add to the index, you're creating a file in the index that appears nowhere else.

Imagine a really simple repository with just *one* file, `README`.  You clone the repository and are on `master`.  The situation looks like this:

```
HEAD      index    work-tree
------    ------    ------
README    README    README
```

All three copies of `README` are identical (though secretly, Git's HEAD and index versions are compressed, and actually share the underlying disk storage so that there are only two on-disk images for README, the compressed Gitty one and the uncompressed plain one).

Now you fire up your favorite editor and modify `README`.  Let's call this `README;1` just to have a horrifying syntax<sup>2</sup> for identifying "a different version of the file". :-)  Now you have this:

```
HEAD      index    work-tree
------    ------    ------
README    README    README;1
```

But, you made a big change, so you decide you want to interactively add some hunks of the change, using `git add -p` or whatever.  Once you do this, you wind up with *this:*

```
HEAD      index    work-tree
------    ------    ------
README    README;2  README;1
```

That is, there are now, literally, three *different versions* of that file that you are working with simultaneously: the committed one that you can't change; the work-tree one that you did change; and the index one, that you created as a Frankensteinian hybrid of the `HEAD` and work-tree versions.

Since there is only one index, there's only one place available in which to create this intermediate version of the file.  So you have to create it, then commit it.  Committing makes a *new* commit, which gets a new unique hash ID, and then makes that new commit become the HEAD commit, so that you now have:

```
HEAD      index    work-tree
------    ------    ------
README;2  README;2  README;1
```

That frees up the index to make yet another new variant of the file: the second version of `README` is safely saved, completely unchangeable (and mostly-permanent), in the `HEAD` commit.

---

<sup>2</sup>This is, in fact, the syntax for versioned files in VMS.

---

[In a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473768/is-it-possible-to-stage-multiple-sets-of-changes-separately-in-git#comment81902113_47473768), mkrieger1 linked to [a question where the answers suggest using the fixup and autosquash features of `git rebase`, including using `git commit --fixup` to record a commit for autosquashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103589/how-can-i-easily-fixup-a-past-commit).  These, like `git commit --amend`, make use of a very useful property of Git's branch names.

A branch name, in Git, points to *exactly one commit*.  The set of commits contained within a branch is determined by starting from that one commit, which Git calls a *tip* commit, and working backwards: that commit has a parent, the parent commit has another parent, and so on.  Each commit is stored under its big ugly commit hash ID: the branch name contains the hash ID of the tip commit, and each commit contains the hash ID of its parent:

```
... <--E <--F <--G   <-- master
```

We say that `master` "points to" the tip commit `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on.

Since no commit can *ever* be changed, the internal arrows always point backwards, and don't really need to get drawn, which is handy since it's hard to do well in ASCII on stackoverflow. :-)  So I draw this instead as:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
```

(I keep the arrow in front of the branch name, because branch names *do* move.)

Now, this means is that if we make a *new* commit whose parent is not the normal "current commit hash ID", but instead is the *parent* of the current commit, and then make the current branch name point to the new commit we just made, we *seem* to have replaced the current commit:

```
         H   <-- master
        /
...-E--F--G
```

We haven't *actually* changed any commits, but it *looks like we did* when we run `git log`, because with nothing pointing to `G`, Git doesn't show it.  Git starts by showing us new commit `H`, then moves back to commit `F`, then moves back to `E`, and so on.

This is what you get with `git commit --amend`: the new commit simply has, as its parent, whatever parent the current (well, now ex-current) commit has.

The `git rebase` command takes this to a new level: instead of just one commit, we can copy many commits, making some slight change(s) as we go.  With interactive rebase, we have Git use `git cherry-pick` on each to-be-copied commit.  The copies can go after any commit you like, though for things like autosquash, you generally do the copies in-place:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch
```

where `J` is a fixup for `H`.  Now you run `git rebase -i --autosquash <hash of G>` and Git generates the commands:

```
pick <hash-of-H>
pick <hash-of-I>
pick <hash-of-J>
```

which, if run totally straightforwardly, would result in:

```
             H'-I'-J'   <-- branch
            /
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   [abandoned]
```

But rather than running them, the autosquash feature notices that `J` itself has, as its one line commit subject, a prefix: `fixup! <subject>`.  The `<subject>` part of this matches `H`'s commit subject, so the autosquash code changes the instructions to:

```
pick <hash-of-H>
fixup <hash-of-J>
pick <hash-of-I>
```

Executing these instructions gives:

```
             HJ--I'   <-- branch
            /
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   [abandoned]
```

where `HJ` is the automatically squashed `H`+`J`, using `H`'s commit message.

---

Now, once again, the problem here is that there's just the one index, and you're building your intermediate images *in* that one index.

If you use `git worktree add`, you can make as many work-trees as you like.  Each has its own index, and of course its own separate work-tree as well.  But there's one very strong constraint Git imposes: *each work-tree must be on a different branch.*

This may not be a problem after all.  Remember that in Git, branches are insanely cheap: making a *new* branch costs just one disk block, holding one 41-byte file.  (A future implementation might change these details but branches will remain absurdly cheap.)

Let's go back to this drawing:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

We can create a new branch now, and all that Git does is write a file that *also* points to commit `J`.  This is why we add `(HEAD)` to the drawing, so that we know which branch our work-tree is using:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch (HEAD), br2
```

We can now add, or copy, or rebase, or whatever, however we like.  The new commits, which are entirely read-only and mostly permanent, are safe and always separate from the old commits.  The new name, `br2`, safely keeps the original commits, no matter what we do with them.  Or, we can switch `HEAD` to `br2` and let the old name, `branch`, keep the original commits safe:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch, br2 (HEAD)
```

Now let's do something with `H-I-J` just like before:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I--J   <-- branch
            \
             HJ--I'   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

If you make a new worktree, you can make it have a new branch.  The new worktree shares all the old commits, and all the old branches.

Git prohibits you from having two work-trees using the *same* branch because then they would both point to the same commit and yet have two index files and two work-trees.  When you made a new commit in one of these, that would use the index in that one, and change the *shared* branch to point to the new commit.  The result is that the other of these two would still have its old (now stale) index and old (now stale) work-tree.  The Git authors deemed this to be too confusing, and simply outlawed it.  *Because* branches are so cheap, this is actually pretty reasonable: just make a new branch for each new work-tree.

The advantage you have here is that you not only have multiple index files, you also have multiple work-trees.  You can stop trying to play index file tricks with extra versions of each file (`git add -p`): just make the work-tree file look the way you want, and then *test* it, and then commit it.  All of these are in temporary work-trees on what could be temporary branches, if they don't work out all that well.  If they *do* work out well, use the best one as the final result.  Simply remove (`rm -rf`) all the lesser work-trees and (`git branch -D`) "didn't work out after all" temporary branches once you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I could find is https://github.com/ustramooner/gitstage

Introduced in this blog post: http://ben.villagechief.com/2012/01/multiple-git-staging-areas.html

> The workflow scenario I use is generally something like this
>
> 1. Run git gui
> 2. Realise that I need to split the commit into 2... duhhhh
> 3. Close git gui without commiting
> 4. Run gitstage commit1, which creates a staging area called 'commit1' and then opens the git gui again
> 5. Make note of what I've staged so far in the git gui Commit Message textbox
> 6. Close the git gui.
>
> - gitstage will now creates a commit of the currently staged index
> - gitstage also puts any messages you were writing in the git gui in .git/gitstage/commit1.msg 7 Run gitstage commit2, which creates
>   another staging area and opens git gui.
>
> 8. Add other files/hunks/lines to the new staging area in the gui
> 9. Repeat steps 4-8 multiple times. Each time you swap the messages you write will be kept
> 10. Committing: click commit in the gui and close the gui
>
> - this then removes the staging area
> - commit any other remaining staging areas
> - end of work flow